# Linking imported proto file in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

Based on a [HelloWorld](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld) from grpc, I have created a project with my own proto file. This proto file also imports another proto file in the same directory:

MainProto.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package MyProject;
option csharp_namespace = "MyProject";

option optimize_for = SPEED;
option cc_enable_arenas = true;
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "CommonUtils.proto";
....
```

Followed by a bunch of enums, messages and services, some of which use the enums/messages from CommonUtils.proto.

In the CMakeLists.txt file, I generate the .cc and .hh based on the MainProto.proto file. However, this does not seem to generate the necessary files for CommonUtils.proto, which are then detected as errors in MainProto.pb.h and the other generated header files.

My question is:

1. How do I modify my CMakeLists or Makefile to also build the headers and cc files for CommonUtils?
2. How do I link the generated files together to avoid "unresolved external symbol" errors?

I have tried replacing the proto file in my CMakeList.txt file (the lines # Proto file and # Generating source) with the CommonUtils.proto, and then replacing it and running with the original MainProto.proto, but I get a bunch of unresolved external symbol errors in the generated MainProto.pb.h for all the fields that should be imported from CommonUtils.proto.

My CMakeLists.txt is similar to the HelloWorld, with only greeter_async_client and greeter_async_server and the rest removed:

```
# Copyright 2018 gRPC authors.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
# cmake build file for C++ helloworld example.
# Assumes protobuf and gRPC have been installed using cmake.
# See cmake_externalproject/CMakeLists.txt for all-in-one cmake build
# that automatically builds all the dependencies before building helloworld.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

project(MainProto C CXX)

if(NOT MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
else()
  add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600)
endif()

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

if(GRPC_AS_SUBMODULE)
  # One way to build a projects that uses gRPC is to just include the
  # entire gRPC project tree via "add_subdirectory".
  # This approach is very simple to use, but the are some potential
  # disadvantages:
  # * it includes gRPC's CMakeLists.txt directly into your build script
  #   without and that can make gRPC's internal setting interfere with your
  #   own build.
  # * depending on what's installed on your system, the contents of submodules
  #   in gRPC's third_party/* might need to be available (and there might be
  #   additional prerequisites required to build them). Consider using
  #   the gRPC_*_PROVIDER options to fine-tune the expected behavior.
  #
  # A more robust approach to add dependency on gRPC is using
  # cmake's ExternalProject_Add (see cmake_externalproject/CMakeLists.txt).
  
  # Include the gRPC's cmake build (normally grpc source code would live
  # in a git submodule called "third_party/grpc", but this example lives in
  # the same repository as gRPC sources, so we just look a few directories up)
  add_subdirectory(../../.. ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grpc EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
  message(STATUS "Using gRPC via add_subdirectory.")

  # After using add_subdirectory, we can now use the grpc targets directly from
  # this build.
  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF libprotobuf)
  set(_REFLECTION grpc++_reflection)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC protoc)
  else()
    set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)
  endif()
  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP grpc++)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
  else()
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)
  endif()
elseif(GRPC_FETCHCONTENT)
  # Another way is to use CMake's FetchContent module to clone gRPC at
  # configure time. This makes gRPC's source code available to your project,
  # similar to a git submodule.
  message(STATUS "Using gRPC via add_subdirectory (FetchContent).")
  include(FetchContent)
  FetchContent_Declare(
    grpc
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
    # when using gRPC, you will actually set this to an existing tag, such as
    # v1.25.0, v1.26.0 etc..
    # For the purpose of testing, we override the tag used to the commit
    # that's currently under test.
    GIT_TAG        vGRPC_TAG_VERSION_OF_YOUR_CHOICE)
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(grpc)

  # Since FetchContent uses add_subdirectory under the hood, we can use
  # the grpc targets directly from this build.
  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF libprotobuf)
  set(_REFLECTION grpc++_reflection)
  set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protoc>)
  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP grpc++)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
  else()
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)
  endif()
else()
  # This branch assumes that gRPC and all its dependencies are already installed
  # on this system, so they can be located by find_package().

  # Find Protobuf installation
  # Looks for protobuf-config.cmake file installed by Protobuf's cmake installation.
  set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
  find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${Protobuf_VERSION}")

  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)
  set(_REFLECTION gRPC::grpc++_reflection)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC protoc)
  else()
    set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)
  endif()

  # Find gRPC installation
  # Looks for gRPCConfig.cmake file installed by gRPC's cmake installation.
  find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")

  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
  else()
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)
  endif()
endif()

# Proto file
get_filename_component(hw_proto "protos/mainproto.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(hw_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mainproto.pb.cc")
set(hw_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mainproto.pb.h")
set(hw_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mainproto.grpc.pb.cc")
set(hw_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mainproto.grpc.pb.h")

add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}"
      COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${hw_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${hw_proto}"
      DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")

# Include generated *.pb.h files
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Targets greeter_[async_](client|server)
foreach(_target
  greeter_async_client greeter_async_server)
  add_executable(${_target} "${_target}.cc"
    ${hw_proto_srcs}
    ${hw_grpc_srcs})
  target_link_libraries(${_target}
    ${_REFLECTION}
    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
    ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
endforeach()
```

And my Makefile is the same:

```
#
# Copyright 2015 gRPC authors.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

HOST_SYSTEM = $(shell uname | cut -f 1 -d_)
SYSTEM ?= $(HOST_SYSTEM)
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++`\
           -pthread\
           -lgrpc++_reflection\
           -ldl
else
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++`\
           -pthread\
           -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed\
           -ldl
endif
PROTOC = protoc
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH ?= `which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)`

PROTOS_PATH = ../../protos

vpath %.proto $(PROTOS_PATH)

all: system-check greeter_async_client greeter_async_server

greeter_async_client: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_async_client.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

greeter_async_server: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_async_server.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.PRECIOUS: %.grpc.pb.cc
%.grpc.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $<

.PRECIOUS: %.pb.cc
%.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --cpp_out=. $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.pb.cc *.pb.h greeter_async_client greeter_async_server


# The following is to test your system and ensure a smoother experience.
# They are by no means necessary to actually compile a grpc-enabled software.

PROTOC_CMD = which $(PROTOC)
PROTOC_CHECK_CMD = $(PROTOC) --version | grep -q libprotoc.3
PLUGIN_CHECK_CMD = which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
HAS_PROTOC = $(shell $(PROTOC_CMD) > /dev/null && echo true || echo false)
ifeq ($(HAS_PROTOC),true)
HAS_VALID_PROTOC = $(shell $(PROTOC_CHECK_CMD) 2> /dev/null && echo true || echo false)
endif
HAS_PLUGIN = $(shell $(PLUGIN_CHECK_CMD) > /dev/null && echo true || echo false)

SYSTEM_OK = false
ifeq ($(HAS_VALID_PROTOC),true)
ifeq ($(HAS_PLUGIN),true)
SYSTEM_OK = true
endif
endif

system-check:
ifneq ($(HAS_VALID_PROTOC),true)
    @echo " DEPENDENCY ERROR"
    @echo
    @echo "You don't have protoc 3.0.0 installed in your path."
    @echo "Please install Google protocol buffers 3.0.0 and its compiler."
    @echo "You can find it here:"
    @echo
    @echo "   https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0"
    @echo
    @echo "Here is what I get when trying to evaluate your version of protoc:"
    @echo
    -$(PROTOC) --version
    @echo
    @echo
endif
ifneq ($(HAS_PLUGIN),true)
    @echo " DEPENDENCY ERROR"
    @echo
    @echo "You don't have the grpc c++ protobuf plugin installed in your path."
    @echo "Please install grpc. You can find it here:"
    @echo
    @echo "   https://github.com/grpc/grpc"
    @echo
    @echo "Here is what I get when trying to detect if you have the plugin:"
    @echo
    -which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
    @echo
    @echo
endif
ifneq ($(SYSTEM_OK),true)
    @false
endif
```

[Here is the output of CMake as run from Visual Studio.](https://pastebin.com/2QQu0r4U)

Comment: what's the output of CMake ?

Comment: @avrono Thank you for the response. Do you mean, what is the output of CMake when I run it as is (referencing the one proto file with the import statement)? I updated my question with the (abridged) output.